# playframework2におけるslickを利用したSQLインジェクション対策

Tags: sql, scala, playframework, slick

現在，フォームから入力された単語からタイトルに一致したものの一覧表示を行おうとしているのですが，

```
def findByWord(word:String): Future[Seq[Item]] = db.run {
  Query.filter(row => (row.title like "%"+word+"%").result
}
```

このように変数を組み込んでいます。
SQLのインジェクション対策はできているのでしょうか？

Answer (score 0):

手元で動作確認できないんですが、できていないはずです。
`"%"+word+"%"`の部分は`"%"+word+"%".bind`と書く必要があった気がします。